# TypeScript: How to create a generic function handling different parameter types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that can be called with diferent parameters like so:

```
const typeToFn = {
  text: (value: string) => value,
  integer: (value: number) => value,
};

type Type = keyof typeof typeToFn;

type Value<TType extends Type> = Parameters<(typeof typeToFn)[TType]>[0]

function callFn<TType extends Type>(type: TType, value: Value<TType>) {
  const fn = typeToFn[type]

  return fn(value)
}
```

However, typescript does not know what the type of "value" should be. It gives the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. (2345)
```

How can I make typescript understand that value is a "string" when the type is "text" and so on?

PS.: This is a simplified example, the actual code has a lot more "types" (not just string and integer)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript can only follow logic like this when presented in a particular way as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  You need to write a "base" key-value map type:

```
type TypeMap = {
    text: string;
    integer: number;
}
```

and make your values either of that type or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type:

```
const typeToFn: { [K in keyof TypeMap]: (value: TypeMap[K]) => TypeMap[K] } = {
    text: (value: string) => value,
    integer: (value: number) => value,
};
```

And write all your operations as [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the base type or mapped types over it:

```
function callFn<K extends keyof TypeMap>(type: K, value: TypeMap[K]) {
    const fn = typeToFn[type]
    return fn(value);
}
```

It's not a very intuitive mapping for most people, but as far as I know it's the only affordance the language has to follow correlated relationships among types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQU9WAgA9gAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuXfBwxia8+gVwC2AI26sAvtmwBjAPb0qBeDBkAxeuUxQA2gGkoDKAGsIIGQDNY8ZGAC65ABQA3JABs+EcnEjXdNgJToAHyW3ii+UGLoWGx4hCQOzm4elDQMjAFowYnuADQx+vSc3Amu7ryCItQZWaUQeWKs2GZ89FLAtHJQUq4uagA8esSE9AAmFEYm5iGIKIH2oJDkOjlQ2cleM2C+ATj4XXIKZvRRCxDKalqnNvnUEMB81MdHTrV+2GJAA)